# Java: Can list hold classes implementing more interfaces

Tags: java, generics

I am writing `NetworkExecutor` in Java. I need my `Runnable` class to implement `Serializable` too, to be able to send it through the network. I wanted to make my own interface NetworkRunnable like this:

```
public interface NetworkRunnable extends Runnable, Serializable{}
```

but then all classes are required to implement `NetworkRunnable`, although this interface is empty and just unifies `Runnable` and `Serializable` interface. I would like to allow classes implementing `Runnable` and `Serializable` to be used too. I found it is a possibility to write generic function:

```
public <T extends Runnable & Serializable> void execute(T command)
```

This allows using classes implementing just `Runnable` and `Serializable`, but I was not able to write `List` holding these objects. I tried something like:

```
List<? extends Runnable & Serializable> list=new LinkedList<>();
List<Runnable & Serializable> list=new LinkedList<>();
```

but it doesn't work. As a solution I can write just `List<Runnable>` and use it because function `<T extends Runnable & Serializable> void execute(T command)` will accept just `Runnable` implementing `Serializable` too, but it looks like an ugly solution for me.

Is there a way to write List of classes implementing multiple interfaces at once? Or can I somehow specify, that all classes implementing `Runnable` and `Seriablizable` implement `NetworkRunnable` interface too?

EDIT:

I am sorry, I probably didn't specify my problem well. I want to do something like:

```
public class NetworkThreadPool{
    private List<Runnable & Serializable> waiting=new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public <T extends Runnable & Serializable> void execute(T command) {
        waiting.add(command);
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to declare `List` of both `Runnable` and `Serializable`.

Comment: Java serialization is not the only or even the best choice for network communication.  You can use XML, JSON, Protobuf, or any number of other choices.  I think your requirement is too wishy washy.  If you require both, spell out both.  Don't waffle.

Comment: What's wrong with having `public <T extends Runnable & Serializable> void execute(T command)` as you mention, and then declare the list with `List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I can do this, but this is not what I want. I don't want List of classes, I want List of whatever classes implementing Runnable and Serializable. My execute() function would just add it's argument to LinkedList declared outside of `execute()` function, not return or use List<T> inside itself.

Answer (score 10):

Java doesn't allow you to declare a generic variable with more than one type, only classes and methods may use multiple bounds with the `<T extends Foo & Bar>` syntax. This is *usually* not a problem, as in regular code you can usually get by with singular typing (`List<Runnable>`), using the actual type (`List<MyRunnableAndSerializable`) or in some cases creating a more specific interface (`List<IRunnableAndSerializable`).

```
List<NetworkRunnable> list1;
List<OtherSimilarClass> list2;

public <T extends Runnable & Serializable> void execute(List<T> list) {
    ...
}
```

The method accepts both and obviously the lists are typed just fine.

---

However your problem comes from the fact that you have a *non-generic* class with a *generic* method, so you don't have a type `T` for the `List`.

**In this case** if `Runnable & Serializable` is what you need, then you could safely type it as `List<Runnable>` since `Serializable` is just a marker interface and `execute()` makes sure the contents are also `Serializable`. If the second interface had methods you needed to call, this would of course fail (in this case see the wrapper based answer by @daniu).

---

In a general situation the Java syntax doesn't allow you to handle this in a straightforward way. You can use a wrapper, but if you want to avoid creating a class just for that you might as well make it a raw list, access it through typed methods to keep it typesafe to **outside** users and internally use casts and `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to ignore warnings and show you know what you're doing. That's how it's usually done inside the JDK when Java's generics fail to achieve what is needed.

Comment: Also, you can now use `List<T> list = new ArrayList<>()` in the method body, which as I understand it is what OP was having trouble with without `T`.

Comment: `If the second interface had methods you needed to call, this would of course fail`. What do you mean exactly by fail? An ugly solution (that would work) is you can still cast that object (of type Runnable) to the second interface with some method (since that object implements both). Am I right?

Comment: @user7 you can do a lot of ugly things, but the answer is concerned with finding non-ugly solutions. We can type to `Runnable` because `Serializable` doesn't have methods. We're trying to avoid casting.

Comment: I agree that we have to avoid ugly things. Since you said it would fail, I was thinking if it could fail with some ClassCastException. That's the part I wanted to get clarified on.

Comment: @user7 I meant the solution will fail and you'll need to do something different, like casting.

Comment: Ok... Makes sense... Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Well since you only have one method everything goes through, you can simply create a Wrapper class and wrap/unwrap on demand.

```
class NetworkRunnable<T extends Runnable & Serializable> implements Runnable, Serializable {
    private T delegate;
    public NetworkRunnable(T del) {
        delegate = del;
    }
    public T unwrap() {
        return delegate;
    }

    public void run() { delegate.run(); }
}

public class NetworkThreadPool{
    private List<NetworkRunnable> waiting=new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public <T extends Runnable & Serializable> void execute(T command) {
        waiting.add(new NetworkRunnable(command));
    }
}
```